# Is it possible to test the validity of the SSL certificate using Protractor?

Tags: ssl, protractor

I want to automatically test the validity of the SSL certificate. If the validity is nearing in 1 month, then the test should fail.

Is it possible to have the SSL certificate validation automatically?